# Alternate word for [ASAP] "as soon as possible"

Tags: single-word-requests

I have requested for some access request from my colleague and I haven't got any reply from his side. To remind him about my request, instead of

> ASAP give access to me.

Please suggest a perfect word, with polite sound.

Comment: The word choice here is all about the relative status of the asker and the askee.  Anything from 'DO IT NOW, A--HOLE!" to "Please get back to me at your earliest convenience, as this is an urgent matter" might be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Please **expedite** this request. [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/expedite)

> To speed up the progress of or execute quickly:

If someone says, "Let me expedite the process," that's speed things up. Waited in line a long time, then you must have wished someone could expedite things. A driver can expedite his commute ... by going faster!

Answer (score 0):

The very fact As soon As Possible has gained it's own acronym is pretty good proof there isn't a generally considered better phrase, or it would be used instead.

Writing it out in full is politer than the shouted capitols acronym, but even politer is to explain why you are important and should jump the queue of other tasks waiting.

Maybe you should ask for this to be moved to inter personal skills?